# Ripple effect only on selected item from items in the layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have a list of layouts and would like to show ripple effect only on the selected item. However the current code is highlighting every layouts inside the parent layout.Appreciate your help!

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#6792" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/layout_list_item_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Item # 1" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#6792" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/layout_list_item_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:text="Item # 2" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#6792" />

                       <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/layout_list_item_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:text="Item # 3" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#6792" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Below are the styles for the background for ripple effect below and above v21

### layout_list_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#ffc20e" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#ffffff"/>
</selector>
```

### layout_list_item_selector.xml (v-21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffc20e">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="#ffffff" />
</ripple>
```

Comment: I manage to fix it through the code where you need to set the background         layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_list_item_selector);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix it through the code where you need to set the background layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_list_item_selector);

Answer (score 0):

use this library 
this gives a android lollipop effect also include Ripple effect you want
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary